# modx revo: wayfinder doesn't sort by menuindex

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

By default, the wayfinder plugin in modx revo should sort by menuindex. This doesn't seem to work. I have the following:

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`2` &level=`1` &ignoreHidden=`TRUE` &outerClass=`news` &sortBy=`menuindex` &sortOrder=`DESC`]]
```

I suspect it's something stupid I overlooked...

**EDIT**: I've made it work now.

I looked into the wayfinder code in `wayfinder.class.php`. The following line was commented out:

```
$c->groupby($this->modx->getSelectColumns('modResource','modResource','',array('id')));
```

It happened because of the following comment in the code:

```
/* not sure why this groupby is here in the first place. removing for now as it causes issues with the sortby clauses */
```

Maybe this will help someone in the future.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please write it on answer textarea and mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the wayfinder code in wayfinder.class.php The following line was commented: $c->groupby($this->modx->getSelectColumns('modResource','modResource','',array('id')));

It was commented out because of the following comment in the code:

/* not sure why this groupby is here in the first place. removing for now as it causes issues with the sortby clauses */

Maybe this helps anyone in the future